# AVAudioRecorder, AudioKit issues , iOS 13.1.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, avaudiorecorder, audiokit

I am not sure what is going on but I cannot seem to initialize a AVAudioRecorder object successfully, given certain audio settings for a device above iOS 13.0

EDIT: commented below. but this works on 13.0 & 13.1 but not the two following patches, 13.1.1 and 13.1.2. ???

Xcode 11

Swift 5

AudioKit pod v4.9(just FYI, dont think this is the problem)

//audio Settings

```
private let audioSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.medium.rawValue
    ]


do {
     audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: actualRecordingPath, settings: audioSettings)
      audioRecorder?.record()
      state = .recording
      try AudioKit.start()
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerDidUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } catch let error{
       print("start recording", error.localizedDescription)
       return
      }
```

The specific error(s) includes:

> AVAudioEngine.mm:160   Engine@0x2835411b0: could not initialize, error
>   = -10868
>
> AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1397:Initialize: (err =
>   AUGraphParser::InitializeActiveNodesInInputChain(ThisGraph,
>   *GetInputNode())): error -10868
>   Blockquote
>
> AudioKit+StartStop.swift:restartEngineAfterConfigurationChange(_:):160:error
>   restarting engine after route change

i was able to find this link:

https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-10868

and its looking like maybe a format is not supported?

Anyone got any idea what's going on here? Again, no error on iOS 13.0, just doesn't work on 13.0+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with iOS 13.1.1 and 13.1.2. I've been using AudioKit's `AKNodeRecorder` in my code, and it turned out that I forgot to route  to `AudioKit.output` the node which my `AKNodeRecorder` was recording. All I had to do was to add a mixer or booster after my node, set that new node's gain to 0, and then route that to the output.

Here's the broken version:

```swift
let mic = AKMicrophone()!
let recorder = AKNodeRecorder(node: mic)!
AudioKit.start()!
```

Here's the working version:

```swift
let mic = AKMicrophone()!
let recorder = AKNodeRecorder(node: mic)!
let recorderGain = AKBooster(mic, gain: 0)
AudioKit.output = recorderGain
AudioKit.start()!
```

To explain why that is needed: AudioKit traverses your processing graph from the output node backward. Anything that is not connected to that graph may not get properly initialised, and its behaviour is undefined. You can observe such undefined behaviour in that your code works on older iOS versions, but not current ones.

*"But AKNodeRecorder is not connected to my graph"*, you may say. It turns out that AKNodeRecorder is not actually a node, but a tap.

A tap can sit "on top" of a node. There can always be only one tap on top of a node. Other examples of taps are the `AKFFTTap`. Generally speaking, taps consume audio, but don't generate any audio, and thus they cannot be part of an audio graph - the only node that cannot generate anything is the final node, `AudioKit.output`.

In other words, your audio graph should look like this:

```
 recordingtap
 |
mic -> gain0 -> output
```

Note that the gain is only needed if you don't want to hear your microphone on your output.

Comment: thanks for the comment! My question would be - why would it just stop working, the way I have it in 13.1.1 and 13.1.2(and it works in 13.1)? I am not using AKNodeRecorder. I am using AKNodeOutputPlot though. No where in the code before now do i set the output to anything.

Comment: "No where in the code before now do i set the output to anything." That's exactly the problem. As I wrote in my comment, this leads to undefined behaviour. When you call `AudioKit.start()`, AudioKit will traverse the graph and make sure that all nodes are coherently configured. If they aren't connected, you rely on each node's default configuration, which may or may not work, and may of course change, even between minor versions, as there are no guarantees for the default configuration. If you use AudioKit, I recommend using it entirely, and not rely on a mix of it and raw AVFoundation code.

Comment: Note that when you use `AVAudioRecorder` in conjunction with `AudioKit`, `AudioKit` will try to configure parts of your audio system, but then `AVAudioRecorder` might configure its part differently. So even though it is not a node as it's not an AudioKit class, it still isn't connected to the graph, and thus AudioKit cannot take care of configuring your audio system in a way that all parts work well with each other. That's why I recommend simply using AudioKit for all the parts.

Comment: Thomas - thanks so much for the help! It looks like it worked. Its just baffling that it worked at all before - something as important as setting the output and it worked up until iOS 13.1 but not 13.1.x. Really weird. So you are saying that you can just use AudioKit to record and playback instead of using both?

Comment: Yep, absolutely. `AudioKit` will handle the recording just fine for you. Just remember: at most one tap per node (and `AKNodeRecorder` is a tap), and all nodes have to be connected to the output (either directly or via other nodes), even if you don't want to hear them (just put a gain in between and set that to 0).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing setting to this:

```
let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
```

Comment: just as an added comment. This works for all devices on 13.1 Just not 13.1.1 and 13.1.2